# Three annulus intersection problem

Tags: metric-geometry, intersection-theory

Recently I faced a problem about intersection of three annuli.
 Imagine having three annuli same dimensions and you put them next to each other into triangular shape like putting together three circles. Now let's say these annuli can slide over each other and form intersections. The question is what is the maximum ratio between annulus' thickness $(R - r)$ and its radius (we have three same annuli), so that when equally sliding them one over each other from starting triangular position, we do not come across triple intersection, but we have to slide them far enough so that the outer circle of each annulus touches the inner circle of its neighbour's annuli.

Comment: Your annuli are apparently in the plane. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by the "radius" of the annulus? The inner radius $r$? the outer radius $R$, the average radius $\frac{r + R}2$? Some other radius?

Comment: Hint: There is not actually a "maximum" ratio with this property (regardless of which radius you are referring to). There is an upper limit to the ratio. That upper limit will occur when the three outer circles do intersect in a single point (the circumcenter of the triangle). So it is not a maximum, as the value itself does not meet the condition. But all lower ratios do meet the condition.

Comment: That is right, they are on a plane. My apologies about the radius I forgot to specify it, I meant the outer radius, so I am looking for a ratio between difference of inner and outer radiuses and outer radius(would not make such difference if choosing inner one). Thanks for the hint, this is what I am looking for: what is the required condition to satisfy this problem and I expressed it as ratio. What is this upper limit and how to find it.